# Apache Proxy and Rewrite Rule for Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite

I set up my Apache server as a proxy for a local server listening on port 8080. It works no matter if I specify a valid proxy or not. Both configurations work.

Configuration 1:

```
<Proxy http://localhost:8080>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:8080$1 [P]
```

Configuration 2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:8080$1 [P]
```

Can anybody explain to me why I don't need to specify a valid proxy as shown in config 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Proxy http://localhost:8080` is meant only to apply permissions and other apache rules (restricting to some client IP, asking for authentication, etc), not for configuring the proxy itself.

The equivalent proxy without mod_rewrite would look like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
```

Or if you need to apply any kind of restriction:

```
<Proxy http://localhost:8080>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from badguy
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Is the second configuration also right?

Comment: Both of your configurations are the same, as you are allowing every connection in the first one, and in the second one it is implyed.  I would **not** recomend using `rewriterule` to do such an open proxy (without restrictions or doing complex rewriting), as it has worse performance than the `proxypass` version.